# Как верно подбирать viewBox, размеры

Tags: svg, inkscape

Задача в том, чтобы исходное svg весило как можно меньше.

Предположим, берем готовую иконку svg, меняем ее размеры либо в большую сторону, либо в меньшу.

Вопрос в том, влияет ли размер холста, размер иконки на вес. То есть на количество координат?

До и после, ничего не трогали. Только изменили viewBox и размер объекта под холст...

И каким образом возможно уменьшить вес? Пользуюсь редактором Inkscape

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Что тут еще добавлять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Вопрос в том, влияет ли размер холста, размер иконки на вес. То есть
> на количество координат?

Размер холста SVG, будь он `width="32"` `height="32"` или ``` width="32000"``height="32000" ``` не сильно влияет на вес файла, разница будет в несколько байт в зависимости от количества значащих цифр.  Хотя физический размер фигур и холста отличается значительно.

На вес файла очень значительно влияет количество значащих цифр в координатах команд SVG:
`path`, `line`, `polyline`, `polygon`, `rect`, `circle`, которые появляются после рисования в Inkscape

Возьмем к примеру файл иконки

```html
<svg width="192" height="192" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 192 192" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g transform="rotate(0 3.14 2.18) translate(16.51195810383291 18.020270094272504) scale(1.2066495923516827)"><g clip-path="url(#a)" clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd"><path d="m120.2 107.3c3e-3 3.439-1.315 6.748-3.681 9.243-2.367 2.495-5.601 3.987-9.035 4.167s-6.807-0.965-9.421-3.2c-2.614-2.234-4.271-5.387-4.628-8.807l-0.07-0.083v-1.201c0-0.04-0.0025-0.079-0.0025-0.119 0-0.039 0.0025-0.078 0.0025-0.118v-18.68c0-0.0395-0.0025-0.0788-0.0025-0.1183s0.0025-0.079 0.0025-0.1185v-31.84c0-14.28-24.98-10.22-27.4-21.27-2.418 11.05-27.4 6.985-27.4 21.27v31.84c0 0.0388 0.0025 0.077 0.0025 0.116s-0.0025 0.077-0.0025 0.1158v18.3c0 0.039 0.0025 0.077 0.0025 0.116s-0.0025 0.077-0.0025 0.116v1.965l-0.2 0.222c-0.3601 2.064-1.199 4.015-2.449 5.697-1.25 1.682-2.876 3.047-4.749 3.987-1.873 0.941-3.939 1.429-6.035 1.427-2.095-3e-3 -4.161-0.496-6.032-1.44-1.87-0.944-3.494-2.313-4.74-3.998-1.246-1.684-2.08-3.637-2.436-5.702-0.3556-2.065-0.2227-4.185 0.3881-6.189 0.6109-2.004 1.683-3.838 3.13-5.353-1.624-1.702-2.772-3.801-3.33-6.086-0.5576-2.286-0.5051-4.677 0.1524-6.936 0.6574-2.259 1.897-4.305 3.594-5.934 1.697-1.629 3.792-2.784 6.076-3.349v-28.76c0-23.4 18.38-37.41 43.46-37.81v-0.00975c0.19 0 0.3775 0.00325 0.5675 0.00475s0.3775-0.00475 0.5675-0.00475v0.00975c25.08 0.409 43.46 14.42 43.46 37.81v28.76c2.305 0.5704 4.419 1.742 6.124 3.396s2.941 3.73 3.583 6.017c0.641 2.287 0.664 4.704 0.067 7.003-0.597 2.299-1.794 4.399-3.467 6.085 2.5 2.512 3.901 5.912 3.897 9.456z" fill="#E7EEF1"></path><g fill="#000"><path d="m120.2 107.3c3e-3 3.439-1.315 6.748-3.681 9.243-2.367 2.495-5.601 3.987-9.035 4.167s-6.807-0.965-9.421-3.2c-2.614-2.234-4.271-5.387-4.628-8.807l-0.07-0.083v-1.201c0-0.04-0.0025-0.079-0.0025-0.119 0-0.019 6e-4 -0.039 0.0013-0.059 6e-4 -0.019 0.0012-0.039 0.0012-0.059v-18.68c0-0.0198-6e-4 -0.0395-0.0012-0.0592-7e-4 -0.0197-0.0013-0.0394-0.0013-0.0591s6e-4 -0.0395 0.0013-0.0592c6e-4 -0.0198 0.0012-0.0396 0.0012-0.0593v-31.84c0-7.729-7.315-10.09-14.41-12.37-5.484-1.767-10.84-3.491-12.58-7.62-0.1699-0.4017-0.3056-0.8262-0.4039-1.276-0.0984 0.4494-0.2341 0.8739-0.4039 1.276-1.746 4.129-7.099 5.854-12.58 7.62-7.096 2.286-14.41 4.643-14.41 12.37v31.84c0 0.0388 0.0025 0.077 0.0025 0.116 0 0.0195-7e-4 0.0388-0.0013 0.0581-6e-4 0.0192-0.0012 0.0383-0.0012 0.0577v18.3c0 0.039 0.0025 0.077 0.0025 0.116 0 0.019-7e-4 0.039-0.0013 0.058s-0.0012 0.038-0.0012 0.058v1.965l-0.2 0.222c-0.3601 2.064-1.199 4.015-2.449 5.697-1.25 1.682-2.876 3.047-4.749 3.987-1.873 0.941-3.939 1.429-6.035 1.427-2.095-3e-3 -4.161-0.496-6.032-1.44-1.87-0.944-3.494-2.313-4.74-3.998-1.246-1.684-2.08-3.637-2.436-5.702-0.3556-2.065-0.2227-4.185 0.3881-6.189 0.6109-2.004 1.683-3.838 3.13-5.353-1.624-1.702-2.772-3.801-3.33-6.086-0.5576-2.286-0.5051-4.677 0.1524-6.936 0.6574-2.259 1.897-4.305 3.594-5.934 1.697-1.629 3.792-2.784 6.076-3.349v-28.76c0-23.4 18.38-37.41 43.46-37.81v-0.00975c0.1232 0 0.2453 0.00136 0.3678 0.00273 0.0057 7e-5 0.0114 1.3e-4 0.0172 2e-4 0.0607 6.7e-4 0.1214 0.00134 0.1825 0.00182 0.061 4.8e-4 0.1218 1.6e-4 0.1825-4.9e-4 0.0438-4.7e-4 0.0876-0.00112 0.1314-0.00177 0.0843-0.00124 0.1687-0.00249 0.2536-0.00249v0.00975c25.08 0.409 43.46 14.42 43.46 37.81v28.76c2.305 0.5704 4.419 1.742 6.124 3.396s2.941 3.73 3.583 6.017c0.641 2.287 0.664 4.704 0.067 7.003-0.597 2.299-1.794 4.399-3.467 6.085 2.5 2.512 3.901 5.912 3.897 9.456zm-2.866-9.457c2.326 2.591 3.62 5.958 3.616 9.457 3e-3 3.631-1.389 7.124-3.887 9.759-2.499 2.635-5.913 4.21-9.54 4.4-3.626 0.19-7.187-1.019-9.947-3.379-2.707-2.313-4.441-5.559-4.863-9.09-0.0635-0.112-0.0975-0.239-0.0975-0.37v-1.201c0-6e-3 -2e-4 -0.014-9e-4 -0.035-5e-4 -0.018-0.0016-0.05-0.0016-0.084 0-0.023 5e-4 -0.046 1e-3 -0.064 3e-4 -7e-3 5e-4 -0.013 6e-4 -0.019 7e-4 -0.021 9e-4 -0.029 9e-4 -0.035v-18.68c0-0.0059-2e-4 -0.0137-9e-4 -0.0353-5e-4 -0.0178-0.0016-0.0494-0.0016-0.083 0-0.0316 1e-3 -0.0614 0.0015-0.0796l1e-4 -0.0034c7e-4 -0.0217 9e-4 -0.0296 9e-4 -0.0355v-31.84c0-3.301-1.421-5.516-3.643-7.197-2.268-1.715-5.352-2.86-8.633-3.937-0.5281-0.1734-1.062-0.3452-1.597-0.5175-2.738-0.8816-5.518-1.777-7.82-2.975-2.111-1.099-3.917-2.5-4.954-4.467-1.037 1.966-2.843 3.368-4.954 4.467-2.302 1.198-5.082 2.094-7.82 2.975-0.5351 0.1723-1.069 0.3441-1.597 0.5175-3.281 1.078-6.365 2.222-8.633 3.937-2.222 1.681-3.643 3.896-3.643 7.197v31.84c0 0.0052 1e-4 0.0123 8e-4 0.0336 6e-4 0.0174 0.0017 0.0488 0.0017 0.0824 0 0.0337-0.0011 0.065-0.0017 0.0824-7e-4 0.0212-8e-4 0.0282-8e-4 0.0334v18.3c0 3e-3 0 7e-3 3e-4 0.016l5e-4 0.018 1e-4 2e-3c6e-4 0.018 0.0016 0.048 0.0016 0.08 0 0.034-0.0011 0.065-0.0017 0.082-7e-4 0.022-8e-4 0.029-8e-4 0.034v1.965c0 0.186-0.069 0.365-0.1936 0.503l-0.0569 0.063c-0.3999 2.1-1.27 4.083-2.546 5.8-1.32 1.776-3.037 3.218-5.014 4.211-1.977 0.992-4.16 1.508-6.372 1.506-2.212-3e-3 -4.394-0.523-6.369-1.52-1.975-0.997-3.689-2.443-5.005-4.222-1.316-1.778-2.197-3.84-2.572-6.021-0.3755-2.18-0.2352-4.418 0.4098-6.535 0.5769-1.893 1.543-3.641 2.834-5.134-1.467-1.698-2.512-3.722-3.046-5.908-0.5888-2.413-0.5333-4.939 0.1609-7.324 0.6941-2.385 2.003-4.546 3.795-6.266 1.65-1.584 3.656-2.743 5.846-3.382v-28.18c0-11.91 4.688-21.48 12.59-28.1 7.865-6.591 18.86-10.23 31.48-10.46 0.0435-0.00784 0.0883-0.01194 0.1341-0.01194 0.1269 0 0.2572 0.00145 0.3826 0.00285 0.0653 7.2e-4 0.1293 0.00144 0.1908 0.00192 0.1123 8.9e-4 0.1928-4.9e-4 0.2805-0.00199 0.0786-0.00134 0.163-0.00278 0.2811-0.00278 0.0457 0 0.0905 0.0041 0.134 0.01194 12.62 0.2279 23.62 3.868 31.48 10.46 7.906 6.625 12.59 16.19 12.59 28.1v28.18c2.212 0.6462 4.237 1.823 5.896 3.432 1.801 1.746 3.106 3.938 3.783 6.353s0.701 4.966 0.071 7.394c-0.57 2.192-1.655 4.213-3.162 5.895z"></path><path d="m67.31 22.21v1e-4l-1e-4 2e-4 -1e-4 1e-4 -0.0015 0.0021-0.0077 0.0115c-0.0072 0.0108-0.0184 0.0277-0.0331 0.0507-0.0296 0.046-0.0735 0.1162-0.1286 0.2096-0.1102 0.1869-0.2652 0.4664-0.4399 0.8309-0.3494 0.7292-0.7765 1.796-1.082 3.14-0.6098 2.683-0.7355 6.474 1.227 10.89 0.0841 0.1893-0.0011 0.4109-0.1904 0.495s-0.4109-0.0011-0.495-0.1904c-2.038-4.584-1.913-8.544-1.273-11.36 0.3197-1.407 0.7675-2.527 1.137-3.298 0.1847-0.3855 0.35-0.6841 0.4702-0.8879 0.0602-0.1019 0.109-0.1801 0.1435-0.2337 0.0172-0.0268 0.0308-0.0475 0.0404-0.0619l0.0113-0.0168 0.0033-0.0049 0.0011-0.0015 4e-4 -6e-4c1e-4 -2e-4 2e-4 -3e-4 0.3021 0.2086l-0.3019-0.209c0.1179-0.1702 0.3515-0.2127 0.5218-0.0948 0.1702 0.1178 0.2127 0.3512 0.0951 0.5214z"></path><path d="m52.34 38.34c0.0896 0.1867 0.0109 0.4107-0.1758 0.5004-6.169 2.961-8.742 6.401-10.4 9.346-0.3548 0.6309-0.6675 1.239-0.9673 1.822-0.053 0.1031-0.1057 0.2055-0.1581 0.3071-0.3466 0.6716-0.6833 1.31-1.048 1.888-0.7343 1.162-1.601 2.108-2.951 2.648-1.29 0.5159-2.382 0.6887-3.317 0.5952-0.9397-0.0939-1.697-0.455-2.312-0.9678-1.209-1.008-1.864-2.601-2.358-3.836-0.0769-0.1923 0.0166-0.4106 0.2089-0.4875s0.4105 0.0166 0.4875 0.2089c0.5058 1.265 1.101 2.672 2.142 3.539 0.5096 0.4247 1.128 0.7199 1.907 0.7978 0.784 0.0784 1.754-0.0613 2.964-0.5454 1.15-0.4598 1.908-1.264 2.596-2.352 0.3458-0.5472 0.6692-1.159 1.016-1.831 0.0516-0.1001 0.1037-0.2014 0.1565-0.304 0.2996-0.5826 0.6194-1.204 0.9817-1.849 1.718-3.055 4.396-6.615 10.73-9.654 0.1867-0.0896 0.4107-0.0109 0.5004 0.1758z"></path><path d="m79.04 38.21c-0.0906 0.183-0.011 0.4026 0.1777 0.4905 6.234 2.903 8.833 6.274 10.51 9.161 0.3585 0.6184 0.6745 1.214 0.9774 1.786 0.0536 0.1011 0.1069 0.2014 0.1598 0.301 0.3502 0.6584 0.6905 1.284 1.06 1.85 0.7421 1.139 1.618 2.066 2.982 2.596 1.303 0.5057 2.408 0.6751 3.352 0.5835 0.9497-0.0921 1.715-0.4461 2.337-0.9488 1.222-0.9879 1.883-2.55 2.383-3.76 0.078-0.1885-0.017-0.4024-0.211-0.4778-0.195-0.0754-0.415 0.0163-0.493 0.2048-0.511 1.24-1.113 2.619-2.164 3.469-0.5153 0.4162-1.14 0.7056-1.927 0.7819-0.7923 0.0769-1.772-0.06-2.995-0.5345-1.162-0.4508-1.928-1.239-2.623-2.306-0.3494-0.5363-0.6762-1.136-1.027-1.795-0.0521-0.0981-0.1048-0.1974-0.1581-0.298-0.3028-0.5711-0.626-1.181-0.9921-1.812-1.736-2.995-4.442-6.485-10.84-9.463-0.1887-0.0879-0.415-0.0107-0.5056 0.1723z"></path></g><path d="m25.19 99.92c1.46-0.0021 2.887 0.429 4.102 1.238 1.215 0.81 2.162 1.961 2.722 3.309 0.56 1.348 0.7076 2.832 0.424 4.264-0.2835 1.432-0.9854 2.748-2.017 3.78-1.031 1.033-2.346 1.737-3.778 2.022-1.432 0.286-2.916 0.14-4.264-0.418s-2.502-1.504-3.313-2.717c-0.8112-1.214-1.244-2.641-1.244-4.1-8e-4 -0.968 0.1892-1.927 0.5591-2.822 0.3698-0.895 0.9123-1.708 1.596-2.393 0.6842-0.685 1.497-1.229 2.391-1.6 0.8942-0.371 1.853-0.5624 2.821-0.563zm82.01 0c1.459-0.0016 2.886 0.43 4.101 1.24 1.214 0.809 2.161 1.961 2.721 3.309 0.559 1.348 0.707 2.832 0.423 4.264-0.284 1.431-0.986 2.747-2.018 3.779-1.031 1.033-2.346 1.736-3.777 2.022-1.432 0.285-2.916 0.139-4.264-0.419-1.349-0.558-2.502-1.504-3.313-2.717-0.811-1.214-1.244-2.641-1.243-4.1-8e-4 -1.956 0.7754-3.832 2.157-5.215 1.382-1.384 3.257-2.162 5.213-2.163zm-82.01-19.29c1.459-0.0014 2.886 0.4298 4.099 1.239s2.16 1.961 2.72 3.308c0.5594 1.347 0.7065 2.83 0.4228 4.262-0.2838 1.431-0.9855 2.746-2.017 3.778-1.031 1.032-2.345 1.735-3.776 2.02s-2.914 0.1396-4.262-0.4184c-1.348-0.558-2.5-1.503-3.311-2.716-0.8107-1.213-1.243-2.639-1.243-4.098-8e-4 -0.9681 0.1891-1.927 0.559-2.822s0.9124-1.708 1.597-2.393c0.6842-0.685 1.497-1.228 2.391-1.599 0.8942-0.3709 1.853-0.5619 2.821-0.5623v1e-3zm82.01 0c1.458-9e-4 2.885 0.4307 4.098 1.24 1.214 0.8098 2.16 1.961 2.719 3.309s0.705 2.83 0.421 4.262c-0.284 1.431-0.986 2.746-2.017 3.777s-2.345 1.735-3.776 2.02c-1.431 0.2849-2.914 0.1392-4.262-0.4189-1.348-0.558-2.5-1.503-3.31-2.716-0.811-1.213-1.243-2.639-1.243-4.098-5e-4 -0.9682 0.1894-1.927 0.5594-2.822 0.371-0.8947 0.913-1.708 1.598-2.393 0.684-0.6849 1.497-1.228 2.391-1.599 0.895-0.3709 1.853-0.5619 2.822-0.5623v1e-3z" fill="#CED6D9"></path><path d="m25.21 80.26c-0.0092-7e-4 -0.0185-0.0011-0.0278-0.0011-1.017 4e-4 -2.025 0.2012-2.964 0.5909-0.9398 0.3898-1.794 0.9609-2.512 1.681-0.719 0.7198-1.289 1.574-1.678 2.514-0.3886 0.9402-0.5882 1.948-0.5874 2.965v-2e-4h0.375l-0.375 3e-4v-1e-4c0 1.533 0.4547 3.032 1.307 4.306 0.8519 1.275 2.063 2.268 3.479 2.854 1.417 0.5863 2.975 0.7393 4.479 0.4397 1.504-0.2997 2.884-1.039 3.968-2.123 1.084-1.085 1.821-2.466 2.119-3.97 0.2981-1.504 0.1436-3.062-0.4442-4.478s-1.582-2.626-2.858-3.476c-1.268-0.8454-2.756-1.298-4.28-1.302zm-0.0542 0.749c-0.9098 0.0038-1.81 0.185-2.651 0.5336-0.8487 0.3521-1.62 0.8679-2.269 1.518s-1.164 1.422-1.515 2.271c-0.351 0.8491-0.5313 1.759-0.5305 2.678v3e-4c0 1.385 0.4107 2.738 1.18 3.89 0.7694 1.151 1.863 2.048 3.143 2.578s2.687 0.6678 4.045 0.3971 2.605-0.9381 3.584-1.918c0.9786-0.9797 1.645-2.228 1.914-3.586s0.1297-2.766-0.4012-4.045c-0.5309-1.279-1.429-2.372-2.581-3.14-1.152-0.7683-2.506-1.178-3.891-1.176-9e-3 1e-4 -0.0179-3e-4 -0.0269-9e-4zm82.06-0.749c-9e-3 -7e-4 -0.018-0.0011-0.028-0.0011-1.017 4e-4 -2.025 0.2012-2.964 0.5909-0.94 0.3897-1.794 0.9608-2.513 1.681-0.72 0.7197-1.29 1.574-1.679 2.514-0.389 0.9401-0.5889 1.948-0.5884 2.965m7.772-7.75c1.524 0.0045 3.012 0.4577 4.279 1.304 1.276 0.8509 2.27 2.061 2.857 3.477 0.588 1.416 0.742 2.974 0.443 4.478-0.298 1.504-1.036 2.885-2.12 3.97-1.083 1.084-2.464 1.823-3.968 2.122-1.503 0.2995-3.062 0.1463-4.478-0.4401s-2.627-1.58-3.479-2.854c-0.8518-1.275-1.306-2.773-1.306-4.306m7.718-7.001c-0.91 0.0038-1.81 0.185-2.651 0.5336-0.849 0.352-1.62 0.8678-2.27 1.518s-1.165 1.422-1.516 2.271-0.532 1.759-0.531 2.678v1e-4c0 1.385 0.41 2.738 1.18 3.89 0.769 1.151 1.862 2.048 3.142 2.578 1.279 0.5296 2.687 0.668 4.045 0.3975s2.605-0.9377 3.584-1.917 1.645-2.227 1.915-3.585c0.269-1.358 0.13-2.766-0.401-4.045-0.53-1.279-1.428-2.372-2.58-3.141s-2.506-1.178-3.89-1.177c-9e-3 1e-4 -0.018-3e-4 -0.027-9e-4zm-78.09 20.46c-1.153-0.768-2.508-1.177-3.893-1.175l-5e-4 -0.375 2e-4 0.375c-0.919 1e-3 -1.829 0.182-2.678 0.534-0.8488 0.353-1.62 0.869-2.269 1.519-0.6494 0.65-1.164 1.422-1.515 2.271-0.351 0.849-0.5313 1.759-0.5306 2.678v1e-3c-1e-4 1.385 0.4108 2.74 1.181 3.892 0.7699 1.151 1.864 2.049 3.144 2.579s2.689 0.668 4.048 0.397c1.359-0.271 2.606-0.939 3.586-1.92 0.979-0.98 1.645-2.229 1.914-3.588s0.129-2.767-0.4025-4.047c-0.5316-1.279-1.431-2.372-2.584-3.141zm-3.894-1.925c-1.017 7e-4 -2.025 0.2017-2.964 0.592-0.9397 0.39-1.793 0.961-2.512 1.681s-1.289 1.574-1.678 2.515c-0.3887 0.94-0.5883 1.947-0.5875 2.965h0.375-0.375c-1e-4 1.534 0.4549 3.033 1.307 4.308 0.8524 1.276 2.064 2.269 3.481 2.856 1.417 0.586 2.977 0.739 4.481 0.439 1.504-0.3 2.886-1.039 3.97-2.125 1.084-1.085 1.821-2.467 2.119-3.972s0.1429-3.064-0.4456-4.481c-0.5885-1.416-1.584-2.626-2.86-3.477-1.276-0.85-2.776-1.303-4.31-1.301m85.9 1.927c-1.153-0.769-2.508-1.179-3.893-1.177-1.856 1e-3 -3.636 0.74-4.948 2.053s-2.048 3.093-2.047 4.95c0 1.385 0.41 2.739 1.18 3.891s1.864 2.05 3.144 2.58c1.28 0.529 2.689 0.668 4.047 0.397 1.359-0.271 2.607-0.939 3.586-1.919s1.646-2.228 1.915-3.587 0.13-2.768-0.402-4.047c-0.531-1.28-1.43-2.373-2.582-3.141zm-3.894-1.927c1.534-0.0017 3.034 0.452 4.31 1.303 1.276 0.85 2.271 2.061 2.859 3.477 0.588 1.417 0.743 2.976 0.445 4.48-0.299 1.505-1.036 2.887-2.12 3.972s-2.466 1.825-3.97 2.124c-1.504 0.3-3.063 0.147-4.481-0.439-1.417-0.587-2.628-1.581-3.48-2.856-0.8526-1.275-1.308-2.774-1.307-4.308m7.744-7.753c-2.055 0.0014-4.025 0.819-5.477 2.273-1.453 1.454-2.268 3.425-2.267 5.48" fill="#000"></path></g><defs><clipPath id="a"><rect width="128" height="128" fill="#fff"></rect></clipPath></defs></g></svg>
```

В каждой координате `path` после запятой 3-4 значащих цифры, что дает в итоге вес файла иконки ***13.36k***, что конечно оч. много для простой иконки

Значительно уменьшает вес файлов оптимизаторы, которые уменьшают кол. значащих цифр в дробной части. Например - 1.

Самый лучший оптимизатор на мой взгляд [**SVGOMG**](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вес файла после оптимизации стал: ***2.89k*** то есть уменьшился в 3 раза.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="192" height="192" fill="none"><g transform="matrix(1.2 0 0 1.2 16.5 18)"><g fill-rule="evenodd" clip-path="url(#a)" clip-rule="evenodd"><path fill="#E7EEF1" d="M120.2 107.3a13.4 13.4 0 0 1-26.8 1.4V56.3c0-14.3-25-10.2-27.4-21.2-2.5 11-27.4 7-27.4 21.2V109l-.2.2a13.4 13.4 0 1 1-23-11.6A13.4 13.4 0 0 1 22 75.3V46.6C22 23.2 40.3 9.2 65.4 8.8h1.1c25.1.4 43.5 14.4 43.5 37.8v28.7a13.4 13.4 0 0 1 6.3 22.5c2.5 2.6 3.9 6 3.9 9.5z"/><g fill="#000"><path d="M120.2 107.3a13.4 13.4 0 0 1-26.8 1.4V107.2a1.7 1.7 0 0 1 0-.1V88.5a1.7 1.7 0 0 1 0-.2V56.4c0-7.7-7.3-10-14.4-12.3-5.5-1.8-10.9-3.5-12.6-7.7l-.4-1.2-.4 1.2c-1.8 4.2-7.1 5.9-12.6 7.7-7.1 2.2-14.4 4.6-14.4 12.3V109l-.2.2a13.4 13.4 0 1 1-23-11.6A13.4 13.4 0 0 1 22 75.3V46.6C22 23.2 40.3 9.2 65.4 8.8h.4a57.2 57.2 0 0 0 .5 0h.2c25.1.4 43.5 14.4 43.5 37.8v28.7a13.4 13.4 0 0 1 6.3 22.5c2.5 2.6 4 6 4 9.5zm-2.9-9.5a14.1 14.1 0 0 1-9.8 23.7 14.2 14.2 0 0 1-14.9-12.9v-1.3a2.4 2.4 0 0 1 0-.1V56.4c0-3.3-1.4-5.5-3.6-7.2a30 30 0 0 0-8.7-4c-.5 0-1-.3-1.6-.4-2.7-1-5.5-1.8-7.8-3-2-1.1-3.9-2.5-5-4.5-1 2-2.8 3.4-4.9 4.5-2.3 1.2-5 2-7.8 3l-1.6.5c-3.3 1-6.4 2.2-8.6 4a8.5 8.5 0 0 0-3.7 7.1V109c0 .2 0 .4-.2.5a14.2 14.2 0 1 1-24.7-11.9 14.2 14.2 0 0 1 6.8-22.8V46.6c0-12 4.7-21.5 12.6-28.1A50 50 0 0 1 65.8 8H66.7A50 50 0 0 1 98 18.5c8 6.6 12.6 16.2 12.6 28v28.3a14.2 14.2 0 0 1 6.6 23z"/><path d="M67.3 22.2a3 3 0 0 0-.2.3l-.4.8a17 17 0 0 0 .1 14 .4.4 0 1 1-.6.3A17.8 17.8 0 0 1 66 23a11.8 11.8 0 0 1 .7-1.2l.3.2-.3-.2a.4.4 0 0 1 .6.4zM52.3 38.3c.1.2 0 .5-.1.5-6.2 3-8.8 6.4-10.4 9.4l-1 1.8a259.7 259.7 0 0 1-1.2 2.2 6.2 6.2 0 0 1-3 2.7 7 7 0 0 1-3.3.5c-1 0-1.7-.4-2.3-1a9.4 9.4 0 0 1-2.3-3.8.4.4 0 0 1 .6-.2 8.7 8.7 0 0 0 2.2 3.5c.5.4 1.1.7 1.9.8.8 0 1.8 0 3-.5 1.1-.5 1.9-1.3 2.6-2.4l1-1.8.1-.3 1-1.9c1.7-3 4.4-6.6 10.7-9.6.2-.1.5 0 .5.1zM79 38.2c0 .2 0 .4.2.5a21.6 21.6 0 0 1 11.5 11l.2.2 1 1.9c.8 1.1 1.6 2 3 2.6 1.3.5 2.4.7 3.4.6 1-.1 1.7-.5 2.3-1 1.2-1 1.9-2.5 2.4-3.7 0-.2 0-.4-.2-.5-.2 0-.4 0-.5.2a8.5 8.5 0 0 1-2.2 3.5c-.5.4-1.1.7-2 .7-.7.1-1.7 0-3-.5-1-.4-1.8-1.2-2.5-2.3a23.8 23.8 0 0 1-1.2-2l-1-1.9c-1.7-3-4.5-6.5-10.9-9.5-.1 0-.4 0-.5.2z"/></g><path fill="#CED6D9" d="M25.2 100a7.4 7.4 0 1 1 0 14.7 7.4 7.4 0 0 1 0-14.8zm82 0a7.4 7.4 0 1 1 0 14.7 7.4 7.4 0 0 1 0-14.8zm-82-19.4a7.4 7.4 0 1 1 0 14.8 7.4 7.4 0 0 1 0-14.8zm82 0a7.4 7.4 0 1 1 0 14.8 7.4 7.4 0 0 1 0-14.8z"/><path fill="#000" d="M25.2 80.3a7.7 7.7 0 0 0-7.8 7.7h.4-.4a7.7 7.7 0 1 0 7.8-7.7zm0 .7a7 7 0 0 0-7 7 7 7 0 1 0 7-7zm82-.7a7.7 7.7 0 0 0-7.8 7.7m7.8-7.7a7.7 7.7 0 1 1-7.8 7.7m7.8-7a7 7 0 0 0-7 7 7 7 0 1 0 7-7zM29 101.5a7 7 0 0 0-4-1.2v-.4.4a7 7 0 0 0-7 7 7 7 0 1 0 11-5.8zm-4-2a7.7 7.7 0 0 0-7.7 7.8h.4-.4a7.8 7.8 0 1 0 7.8-7.8m85.9 2a7 7 0 1 0-7.8 11.6 7 7 0 0 0 7.8-11.6zm-4-2a7.8 7.8 0 1 1-7.7 7.8m7.8-7.8a7.7 7.7 0 0 0-7.8 7.8"/></g><defs><clipPath id="a"><path fill="#fff" d="M0 0h128v128H0z"/></clipPath></defs></g></svg>
```

***Вот таким образом можно уменьшить вес SVG, пользуясь Inkscape.***

Comment: @stylok Я тебе предложил показать **здесь** в ответе свой вариант. Переходить на личности и оценку моей проф. пригодности я не предлагал.  В дополнительном ответе я чётко обосновал, что не оптимизатор делает невозможность анимации, а двойные контуры исходной фигуры. Покажи, как ты справился с этой проблемой. Какая у тебя получилась анимация.

Comment: Ниже показал. Что ещё придумаете в качестве отмазок, о "миллионах мух", использующих оптимизаторы?

Answer (score 0):

Данный дополнительный пост не является ответом, но отвечает на [комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1480365/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-viewbox-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B#) @stylok

> сделали её практически недееспособной для каких бы ни было серьёзных
> манипуляций для анимаций

[***SVGOMG***](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) оптимизатор SVG от [Jake Archibald](https://jakearchibald.com/3) является на данный момент лучшим оптимизатором, которым пользуются миллионы разработчиков. Он убирает всю лишнюю служебную информацию от Inkscape типа:

```
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
```

и позволяет убрать лишние десятичные знаки, что значительно уменьшает вес SVG.

SVGOMG не делает исходник рабочим или не рабочим SVG для анимаций с помощью `stroke-dashoffset`, так это целиком зависит только от способа, как нарисованы контуры SVG фигуры.

***Если фигура SVG нарисована двойными контурами, то анимацию рисования линий не будет просто видно, так как контуры располагаются близко друг к другу.***

Выход здесь один,- заменить двойные контуры на одинарные.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Покажу как  работает анимация на моем ответе с конкурса [Winter Bash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/385129/440057). Происходит рисование одиночного контура (линий) svg иконки парика. Там есть ещё дополнительные анимации, я их не стал вырезать. Если нужно, могу лишнее убрать.

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 125 125" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="border:0px solid">
 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bohfJ.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" /> 
         <!-- glass -->
   <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ll6AQ.png" transform="translate(-70 0)" width="50%" height="100%" >
    <animateTransform id="glass" attributeName="transform" type="translate" values= "30 -40;30 0"  begin="paintCircle.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" />
</image>
  <g fill="none" stroke="grey" stroke-width="1.5"  transform="translate(-5 -15) scale(0.85,0.8)">
 <path  stroke-dashoffset="672"  stroke-dasharray="672" d="m70.8 60.2-13.7 5-7 3.5-4.4 5.9-.1 40.9v23.7l-.5 3.4c-1.8 6.6-10.4 12.5-17.7 12.6-6.2 0-11.5-4.8-14.1-10.5-1.6-3.5-1-8 0-11.7.7-2.1 3.2-6 3.2-6s-3.6-3.7-4.2-6.8c-.8-5 0-9.5 2.5-13.8 2.3-4 9.9-5.6 9.9-5.6s-1.8-27.3.3-40.5C30.3 26.7 57.4 20 80 20c15.5 0 32.3 7.8 42 19.4 5 5.7 8.1 13 8.2 20.9.3 16 .4 40.2.4 40.2s11.6 2 12.6 15.2c.3 4.2-4.3 12-4.3 12s8.3 9.1 3 18.4a18 18 0 0 1-16 9.3c-9-.5-15.7-10.8-15.7-10.8s.5-43.7-.2-68.5c-.1-3.6-3.4-6.9-6.6-8.5a260 260 0 0 0-20-8.2L80 56.8s-1.9-3.4-2.2-3.4c-.8 0-1.2-1.2-1.5-2-.8-2.3-.6-4.9-.3-7.3.4-2.8.3-6.5 2.7-8.2.5-.3 3.2-1.6 2 0-2.3 3.1-2.3 5.4-2.7 8.2-.3 2.4 0 5 .3 7.3.4 2.8-4.4 6.5-3.6 6.5z" >
    <animate id="contour" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="1s" dur="4s" values="672;0" fill="freeze" />
      <animate id="paint" attributeName="fill" begin="5.5s" dur="4s" values="#B6BCBE;#E7EEF1" fill="freeze" />
        
 </path>
  
   <path  fill="none" stroke-dashoffset="38" stroke-dasharray="38" d="M33 70.9s4.2 10 11.2 2.5c1-1 1.8-2 2.7-4a19 19 0 0 1 6.6-8.6c3-2.4 6.7-4.3 6.7-4.3" >
     <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="contour.end+0.5s" dur="1s" values="38;0" fill="freeze" />
 </path>
    <path  stroke-dashoffset="38" stroke-dasharray="38"  d="M93.3 56s6.9 3.5 9.7 6.1c1.9 1.8 2.9 4.5 4.6 6.5 2 2.5 3.5 6 6.6 7a6 6 0 0 0 5-1c1.2-.8 2.4-4 2.4-4" >
       <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="contour.end+1s" dur="1s" values="38;0" fill="freeze" />
 </path> 
     <g>
     <path   stroke-dashoffset="56" stroke-dasharray="56" d="M28 106.6c4.2-.2 9.5 4 9.8 8.3.2 4.6-5 10-9.6 10-4.3.1-8.1-4.9-8.2-9.1 0-4.3 3.7-9 8-9.2z"> 
     <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="contour.end+1.5s" dur="1s" values="56;0" fill="freeze" />
 </path>
     <path   stroke-dashoffset="56" stroke-dasharray="56" d="M28 129.7c4.5 0 9.7 5.1 9.5 9.6-.1 4.3-5.3 8.6-9.6 8.4-4-.1-8.2-4.6-8.3-8.6 0-4.2 4.3-9.3 8.5-9.4z" >
       <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="contour.end+1.5s" dur="1s" values="56;0" fill="freeze" />
 </path>
     <path   stroke-dashoffset="56" stroke-dasharray="56" d="M126.7 106.7c4.3 0 9 4.7 9 9 .1 4.1-4.4 8.9-8.6 9-4.2.1-9-4.3-9.2-8.4-.2-4.4 4.5-9.5 8.8-9.6z">
       <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="contour.end+2s" dur="1s" values="56;0" fill="freeze" />
     </path>
     <path    stroke-dashoffset="56" stroke-dasharray="56" d="M126.5 129.7c4.5.1 9.5 5.4 9.3 9.9-.2 4.1-5.3 8.4-9.5 8.1-4.2-.2-8.5-5.2-8.4-9.4.1-4 4.5-8.6 8.6-8.6z" >
        <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="contour.end+2s" dur="1s" values="56;0" fill="freeze" />
     </path>
         <animate id="paintCircle" attributeName="fill" begin="paint.end-1s" dur="1s" values="#B6BCBE;#C7CDD0" fill="freeze" />
      </g>
    </g> 
     </svg>
```